# Get binary mask in python

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

What is the easiest/fastest way to get a int in python which can be represented by all ones in binary. This is for generating N bit masks.

E.g:

```
If total number of bits is 4, then binary '1111' or int 15
If total number of bits is 8 then, binary '1111 1111' or 255
```

I was under the impression ~0 is for that purpose, looks like that is not the case or I am missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's very easy to achieve with bit shifting:

```
>>> (1<<4)-1
15
```

shifting 4 times 1 to the left gives you `0b10000`, subtract 1 you get `0b1111` aka `15`.

(the `int("1"*4,2)` method is overkill because it involves building a string and parsing it back)